# Displaying SQL results in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am using SQL in vb.net. I believe I have successfully connected to the database and at the moment I am able to display the information I have received in a message box with:

```
    sql = "SELECT ID FROM LoginInformation WHERE Username = '" & txt_Username.Text & "' AND Password = '" & txt_Password.Text & "'"
    DataSets = database.sqlSelect(sql)
    MsgBox(DataSets.Tables("LoginInformation").Rows(0).Item(0))
```

However, I do not want it to show the same cell of the database every time I use this code and I am unsure as to how to display what I am actually looking for with the SQL statement. From the above code, I have tried to find the 'ID' but it will always display the cell located at (0,0)

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should loop throw this `DataSets.Tables("LoginInformation")` to get all the rows and columns.

See this example [quoted from here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.tables(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2):

```
Private Sub PrintRows(ByVal dataSet As DataSet)
   Dim table As DataTable
   Dim row As DataRow
   Dim column As DataColumn
   For Each table in dataSet.Tables
      For Each row In table.Rows
         For Each column in table.Columns
            Console.WriteLine(row(column))
         Next column
      Next row
   Next table
End Sub
```

Comment: Well i am only to return a single value. e.g is the password from the database the same as the word in the text box

Comment: @Owen - Instead of `SELECT ID FROM LoginInformation WHERE ..`, try `SELECT MAX(ID) FROM LoginInformation WHERE ..`. This way you will get only on single value. Then you can do this `dim value as Object = cmd.ExecuteScalar()`